How to install gRPC layer for WildFly?
I'm trying to add a gRPC layer for WildFly 28.
I followed this guide.
I already have a server previously installed without Galleon's help.
I'm stuck on this step:
 galleon.sh install org.wildfly.extras.grpc:wildfly-grpc-feature-pack:0.1.0.Final --layers=grpc --dir=/opt/wildfly

When entering the command, Galleon displays an error.
Error: Install failed.
 * Install failed.
  * /opt/wildfly has to be empty or contain a provisioned installation to be used by the tool

How can I solve the problem of installing gRPC on WildFly?

Did you provision widlfy using : galleon.sh install wildfly:current --dir=/opt/wildfly ? and (given that it is /opt) do you have sufficient permissions ?

@ehsavoie No, I did not use galleon to install this WildlFly. This is an already used server that required gRPC support. It was installed from the archive. The rights to /opt are sufficient. I tried running galleon under the wildfly user, who owns /opt/wildfly. But it still displays the error: Error: Not a galleon installation /opt/wildfly.

@ehsavoie I'm currently deploying a new wildfly server using galleon. Adding gRPC to it was not a problem.
